# Remote Access of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, remote-access

I am new to remote access programming, please dont feel bad to place this question here. I didn't get a beginning yet after a long search.
I heard iPhone can be used as remote for cars, electric devices and even accessing iPhone  from another iPhone. Which library should I use for remote access? Any tutorial available?

Comment: You can talk to other devices via WiFi or bluetooth, nothing that you haven't already heard of. It's standard networking in practice.

Comment: i want to know how "find my iPhone" app works........ ???? If i want to do an app like that . Where should i start.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`External Accessory Framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html). This framework allows you to communicate with "connected devices" (either through bluetooth, or via a physical connection).

If you want anything a bit more complicated you're probably going to have to set one device up as a server and the other as a client and have the two communicate as such.

Another way you could do it is to use an XMPP (aka Jabber) central server and set the two devices up as clients which can push messages to each other to control each other.